# How to create a link to a different template's id using Django template tags?

Tags: html, django

I have a button and I want that button take me to a different template's HTML id. How can I do that using Django template tags?

This is nav.html

```
 <navbar class="name">
    <a href="{% url 'main' %}" class="name">Home</a>
    <a href="{% url 'ministries' %}" class="name">Login</a>
    <a href="{% url 'areas' %}" class="name">Areas</a>
    <a href="{% url 'about' %}" class="name">About Us</a>
</navbar>
```

This is index.html and it has an id called #Ministries

```
<!-- Ministries Section -->
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-32" id="Ministries">
    <h3 class="w3-border-bottom w3-border-light-grey w3-padding-16">Ministries</h3>
  </div>
```

I want Minitries button take to index.html's #Ministries id section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the id to the URL.

```
<a href="{% url 'ministries' %}#Ministries" class="name">Login</a>
```